How can I render a text of markdown in nuxt v3.11.2 using @nuxt/content v2.12.1
Make sure it is rendering on the server side for SEO reasons.
<script setup lang="ts">
const markdown = "# hello world"
</script>

<template>
  <LayoutContent>
    <!-- renders "markdown" here -->
  </LayoutContent>
</template>

I wanted to compile "markdown" into html and render it inside a LayoutContent component.
In addition, I want it to support code highlight.

I will post this comment as a suggestion and not necessarily as an answer, i assume that you also use tailwindcss as you have the tailwind-css in your tag list, if you haven't so checkout the tailwind typography plugin, also for "support code highlight" you may want to basically render vue components into your markdown which some may refer to as MDX, i believe that the nuxt-content  module support this functionality, and i encourage you to look in their docs.

Step 1: Install the packages markdown-it and highlight.js by running the following command in your terminal:
npm install -D markdown-it highlight.js

Step 2: Update your nuxt.config.ts file by enabling support for .server.vue extensions, which enables Server-Side Rendering. To achieve this, add the experimental property with the value componentIslands: true.
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  // ...
  experimental: {
    componentIslands: true,
  },
})

Step 3: Create a new component named HighlightedMarkdown.server.vue and save it in the components directory, then set the content of the component to the following:
<script setup lang="ts">
import markdownit from 'markdown-it'
import hljs from 'highlight.js'

interface PropsType {
  markdown: string
}

const { markdown } = defineProps<PropsType>()

const md = markdownit({
  highlight(str, lang) {
    if (lang && hljs.getLanguage(lang)) {
      try {
        return hljs.highlight(str, { language: lang }).value
      }
      catch (__) {}
    }

    return '' // use external default escaping
  },
})
const html = md.render(markdown)
</script>

<template>
  <div class="prose prose-lg" v-html="html" />
</template>

Step 4: To enable code highlighting, you can install a theme CSS file. You can find more information here.
If you're using tailwindcss in your application, you'll need to include the @tailwindcss/typography plugin. To add the plugin, follow these simple steps:

Run the following command to install the plugin:

npm install -D @tailwindcss/typography


In your tailwind.config.ts file, import the plugin:

import tailwindTypography from '@tailwindcss/typography'


Add the plugin to the plugins inside your tailwind.config.ts file:

plugins: [tailwindTypography()]

Now that all the necessary steps have been completed, you can easily add the HighlightedMarkdown component wherever you need it in your project.
<script setup lang="ts">
const markdown = `
# Heading 1
## Heading 2
### Heading 3
#### Heading 4

\`\`\`javascript
function myFunction () {
  console.log("Hello World")
}
\`\`\`
`
</script>

<template>
  <LayoutContent>
    <HighlightedMarkdown :markdown="markdown" />
  </LayoutContent>
</template>

